# PHP ARRAY - looking for a duplicate value among two of three parameters, and adding it to the third parameter, removing the entire value

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array in php,

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4830)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4831)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4831)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4920)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4920)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4919)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["idu"]=>
    int(4918)
    ["day"]=>
    string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
    ["type"]=>
    int(4)
  }

}
```

parameters like 'idu' and 'day' can be duplicated, but 'idu', 'day', 'type' cannot.

How to make the 'type' parameter combined for identical values for 'idu' and 'day'

e.g. for 'idu'=4831 and 'day'='2023-10-21 16:00:00'
the 'type' parameter has values 4 and 5,

I would like these two items to become one in the form

```
...
array(3) {
     ["idu"]=>
     int(4830)
     ["day"]=>
     string(19) "2023-10-21 16:00:00"
     ["type"]=>
     array(2) {
        [0]=>int(4)
        [1]=>int(5)
     }
   }
...
```

Comment: Can you please put the array in your question using [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export). It will make the live of the person trying to answer your question a lot easier. Or, to put it another way: You say: _"I have an array in php"_, my response would be: _"No you don't, that isn't valid PHP."_.

Comment: Also: If you want to combine two items with `'idu'=4831` why does the resulting item have `'idu'=4830`?

Comment: @volkerschulz Certainly just a typo.

Comment: You could do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190799/12763954).

Comment: @Olivier You're probably right with the typo...

Comment: @Prokul Any feedback on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution including a test case:

```
<?php 

function combineDuplicates(Array $original_array) : Array {
    $resulting_array = [];
    foreach($original_array as $item) {
        $hash = bin2hex($item['idu'] . $item['day']);
        if(!isset($resulting_array[$hash])) {
            $resulting_array[$hash] = $item;
            $resulting_array[$hash]['type'] = [$item['type']];
        } else {
            $resulting_array[$hash]['type'][] = $item['type'];
        }
    }
    return array_values($resulting_array);
}

$original_array = [
0=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4830,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        4
],
1=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4831,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        4
],
2=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4831,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        5
],
3=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4920,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        4
],
4=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4920,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        5
],
5=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4919,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        4,
],
6=>
[
    "idu"=>
        4918,
    "day"=>
        "2023-10-21 16:00:00",
    "type"=>
        4
]
];

var_dump($original_array);
var_dump(combineDuplicates($original_array));
```

Comment: No need to use a hash here. `$item['idu'] . ';' . $item['day']` is enough.

Comment: By definition, `$item['idu'] . ';' . $item['day']` would be a hash too, but you're right, there's no need for `md5` here.

Comment: You can even use a 2-dimensional array like `$result[ idu_value ][ day_value ][] = ...` by which you'd even avoid to build a hash at all

Comment: If `$item['idu']` contains an int and `$item['day']` a date, then `$item['idu'] . ';' . $item['day']` is not a hash, it's a unique key (no collision possible). Not to mention that it's faster to compute than an MD5.

Comment: @HonkderHase This has implications if you want it to return with `array_values()` however.

Comment: @Olivier If `$item['day']` was always an ISO date, you wouldn't even need `';'`. ;)

Comment: You're right. I just have the habit of putting a separator for that kind of thing, even if it's not strictly required.

Comment: @volkerschulz was using `array_values()` a requirement?

Comment: @Olivier And I have the habit of using hashes as array keys as this just makes it more versatile (if you want to return the array as valid JSON for example, no matter what the original values are). I edited my answer to use `bin2hex` instead of `md5` as this is probably less costly and guaranteed to be unique. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @HonkderHase Well, asking for a merge implies the array structure remains the same, in my opinion. But I agree that we can only be 99% sure by what the OP defined.